# Polymer 2.0 - dom-repeat - simple animation

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x, neon-animation

I have build some component in Polymer 2.0, in this component i have `dom-repeat` block in `dom-if`. Is there any simple and fast way to add some animation, on open, and close this repat block?

Here is my code:

```
<template id="drop-down-list-container" is="dom-if" if="{{_isDropDownOpen}}">
        <div id="drop-down-list">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{itemsTitles}}">
                <button on-click="_onDropDownItemClick" class="button-style items">{{item}}</button>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
```

I want to have some simple animations when _isDropDownOpen change state -> from 0 to 1 - entry animation, from 1 to 0 close animation. It is simple to add this? Should I use neon animations?

Comment: Do not use neon-animation, it is deprecated - https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/tree/2.0-preview

Comment: You could do some CSS transitions, as an alternative to Polymer-specific code

Comment: you could also just add a class/attribute to your element and hide/show your div with css. (instead of using dom if) [uses less dom modules so it has "some" performance benefit]

Comment: @daKmoR yes that's possible solution, but i still want to use dom-if

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the iron-collapse, it has animation build in see [iron-collapse](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-collapse/demo/demo/index.html)

Comment: it was one year ago